# QR algorithm is returning incorrect values when trying to find the matrix Q

Tags: c#, matrix, linear-algebra, equation

I have a system of linear equations Ax = b.
I write it as A = QR and my goal is to write an algorithm, which would find the Q matrix (for now at least).

This is my code currently:

```
double[,] A0 = { { 1, 2, 1, 1 }, { 2, -5, 1, 2 }, { 4, -1, 3, 4 }, { 3, -3, 2, 3 } };
double[] b0 = { -7, 3, 0, 2 };
private void QRskaidaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearForm();
            Matrix<double> A = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(A0);
            Matrix<double> B = A.QR().Q;
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Expected result: \n");
            richTextBox1.AppendText(B.ToString() + "\n");
            Vector<double> b = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(b0);
            int n = A.ColumnCount;
            Matrix<double> Q = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseIdentity(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                Matrix<double> z = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(n-i, 1, (j,g) => A[i+j, g+i]);
                Matrix<double> zp = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(n-i, 1);
                zp[0, 0] = Math.Sign(z[0, 0]) * z.L2Norm();
                Matrix<double> omega = z - zp;
                omega = omega / omega.L2Norm();
                Matrix<double> Qi = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseIdentity(n - i);
                Qi = Qi - 2 * omega * omega.Transpose();
                Matrix<double> temp = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(n - i, n - i, (j, g) => A[j+i, g+i]);
                temp = Qi * temp;
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    for (int g = i; g < n; g++)
                    {
                        A[j, g] = temp[j - i, g - i];
                    }
                }
                Matrix<double> Qm = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseIdentity(n);
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                    for (int g = i; g < n; g++)
                    {
                        Qm[j, g] = Qi[j - i, g - i];
                    }
                Q = Q * Qm;
            }
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Result: \n");
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Q.ToString() + "\n");
        }
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
Expected result: 
DenseMatrix 4x4-Double
-0.182574   0.547723   0.743227   0.338055
-0.365148  -0.730297   0.202586   0.540641
-0.730297   0.365148  -0.540641   0.202586
-0.547723  -0.182574   0.338055  -0.743227

Result: 
DenseMatrix 4x4-Double
0.182574  -0.547723  -0.807504  -0.120845
0.365148   0.730297  -0.464175    0.34333
0.730297  -0.365148    0.34333   0.464175
0.547723   0.182574   0.120845  -0.807504
```

The first two columns are with the wrong sign for some reason and the other two are wrong entirely. It looks like I'm close, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fix following : Qm[j, g] = Qi[j - i, g - i];

Comment: Am I doing something wrong in that part? If I understand correctly I'm supposed to put the Qi matrix in the bottom right corner of an identity matrix and then multiply it with Q. If my understanding of the algorithm is correct, this part seems to be working okay

Comment: As i increases the index to the array decreases which will cause the numbers to go into matrix the opposite direction.

Comment: As i increases the size of the matrix Qi decreases, if I do not decrease the indexes I go out of bounds.

Comment: Should be (i + j) and (i + g).

Comment: This also goes out of bounds. With my data Qi is 4x4 when i = 0, 3x3 when i = 1 and 2x2 when i = 2. Qm is always 4x4. i+j and i+g would both go as high as 6 when the Qi matrix is only 2x2.

Comment: There are other issues with the code.  For example what is little 'g' value?

Comment: A counter from i to n used to skip columns before i.

Comment: Then i is going to large.